# creating boolean field in jsp jstl form in spring petclinic

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

The spring petclinic comes with field types in jsp for textual input and selection boxes.  How do I create a field type that gives the user a checkbox to add/edit boolean data?

Here is an example of the tag syntax for inputField and selectField:

```
<petclinic:inputField label="Name" name="name"/>  
<petclinic:selectField name="type" label="Type " names="${types}" size="5"/>
```

You can see a jsp that uses these tags [at this link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/pets/createOrUpdatePetForm.jsp).

The code that defines the inputField tag is [at this link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/inputField.tag).  And the code that defines the selectField tag is [at this link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/selectField.tag).

So how do I set up a custom tag for a boolean data type and a checkbox?  I have never seen this syntax before, and I want to know how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkbox:

```
<%@ attribute name="name" required="true" rtexprvalue="true"
              description="Name of corresponding property in bean object" %>
<%@ attribute name="label" required="true" rtexprvalue="true"
              description="Label appears in red color if input is considered as invalid after submission" %>
<%@ attribute name="names" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" type="java.util.List"
              description="Names in the list" %>
<%@ attribute name="size" required="true" rtexprvalue="true"
              description="Size of Checkbox List" %>
<spring:bind path="${name}">
    <c:set var="cssGroup" value="control-group ${status.error ? 'error' : '' }"/>
    <div class="${cssGroup}">
        <label class="control-label">${label}</label>

        <div class="controls">
            <form:checkboxes path="${name}" items="${names}" size="${size}"/>
            <span class="help-inline">${status.errorMessage}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</spring:bind>
```

Boolean/Radio button:

```
<%@ attribute name="name" required="true" rtexprvalue="true"
              description="Name of corresponding property in bean object" %>
<%@ attribute name="label" required="true" rtexprvalue="true"
              description="Label appears in red color if input is considered as invalid after submission" %>
<%@ attribute name="value" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" type="java.lang.Boolean"
              description="True or False" %>
<spring:bind path="${name}">
    <c:set var="cssGroup" value="control-group ${status.error ? 'error' : '' }"/>
    <div class="${cssGroup}">
        <label class="control-label">${label}</label>

        <div class="controls">
            <form:radiobutton path="${name}" value="${value}"/>
            <span class="help-inline">${status.errorMessage}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</spring:bind>
```